# Get custom attribute value in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have save my custom attribute in quote session but unable to receive its value in cart page. I want to save custom attribute in product session and get value in cart. I use code

```
$quoteItem = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($productId);
$quoteItem->addOption(array('label' => 'buymode', 'code' => 'buymode', 'value' => '2222'));
$quoteItem->save();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you should pass item id to `getItemById`, not product id. Quote item id and product id are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$quoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();
$itemId = null;
foreach($quoteItems as $item){
 if($item->getProductId() == $productId){
   $itemId = $item->getId();
 }
}
if($itemId){
$quoteItem = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
 $quoteItem->addOption(array('label' => 'buymode', 'code' => 'buymode', 'value' => '2222'));
$quoteItem->save();
}
```